# Ruby - ThreadError for Looping Connection

Tags: ruby

I'm working on my first attempts on Sockets and Threading and am running into an issue where I believe I am hitting a thread cap, but not entirely sure.

Basically I have a `server.rb` which opens a TCPServer and a `game.rb` which connects to the server. On the server, when the user connects I output some general information and then want to start reading data that is passed through from the `game.rb`. I believe the problem I am running into is I am just creating a new thread everytime the loop executes and I think I'm meeting the cap. I am also not sure if this is best practice. I wanted to avoid using other APIs until I got a decent grasp on the basics, so I tried to follow the code from https://github.com/sausheong/tanks.

**server.rb**

```
require 'socket'

# lsof -i :2000
# kill ID

class Server
  def initialize(host, port)
    puts "starting arena"

    @server = TCPServer.open(host, port)
    @sprites = Hash.new
    @players = Hash.new

    handle_connection(@server.accept)

  end

  def handle_connection(socket)
    _, port, host = socket.peeraddr
    user = "#{host}:#{port}"
    puts "#{user} has joined!"
    puts "------"

    loop do
      thread = Thread.start(socket) do |client|
        puts 'starting new thread'
        data = socket.readpartial(4096)
        data_array = data.split("\n")

        if data_array && data_array.any?
          begin
            data_array.each do |row|
              message = row.split("|")
              puts message
            end
          rescue Exception => exception
            puts "exception happened?"
            puts exception.inspect
          end
        end
      end
    end # end loop
  rescue EOFError => err
    puts "error"
    puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
    socket.close
    puts err
  end # handle_connection end

end # class end

Server.new('localhost', 2000)
```

**game.rb**

```
# create a server
# join server
# move Player
# communicate to server that player moved
# update players position for server?

require 'gosu'
require 'socket'

class Player
  def initialize
    @image = Gosu::Image.new("media/starfighter.bmp")
    @x = @y = @vel_x = @vel_y = @angle = 0.0
    @score = 0
  end

  def warp(x, y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def turn_left
    @angle -= 4.5
  end

  def turn_right
    @angle += 4.5
  end

  def accelerate
    @vel_x += Gosu.offset_x(@angle, 0.5)
    @vel_y += Gosu.offset_y(@angle, 0.5)
  end

  def move
    @x += @vel_x
    @y += @vel_y
    @x %= 640
    @y %= 480

    @vel_x *= 0.95
    @vel_y *= 0.95
  end

  def draw
    @image.draw_rot(@x, @y, 1, @angle)
  end
end

class Client

  def initialize(host, port)
    @client = TCPSocket.open(host, port)
    send_data("321|123")
  end

  def send_data(data)
    @client.write(data)
  end
  # puts "enter your name:"
  # client.write gets
  #
  # while line = client.gets
  #   puts line.chop
  # end
end

class Tutorial < Gosu::Window
  def initialize(server, port)
    super 640, 480
    self.caption = "Tutorial Game"

    @client = Client.new(server, port)

    @background_image = Gosu::Image.new("media/space.png", :tileable => true)

    @player = Player.new
    @player.warp(320, 240)
  end

  def update
    if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_LEFT or Gosu::button_down? Gosu::GP_LEFT
      @player.turn_left
      @client.send_data("left")
    end
    if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_RIGHT or Gosu::button_down? Gosu::GP_RIGHT
      @player.turn_right
    end
    if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::KB_UP or Gosu::button_down? Gosu::GP_BUTTON_0
      @player.accelerate
    end
    @player.move
  end

  def draw
    @player.draw
    @background_image.draw(0, 0, 0)
  end

  def button_down(id)
    if id == Gosu::KB_ESCAPE
      close
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

Tutorial.new('localhost', 2000).show
```

Comment: Move the `accept` call into `Thread.start`, i.e. `Thread.start(socket.accept) { ... }`. See [`TCPServer`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html) for a simple implementation (the 2nd example).

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't even realize it would try to accept a new connection for every thread if I just passed in the variable `socket` defined as `socket = @server.accept`

This seemed to have fixed the issue. You should answer so I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop: (simplified)

```
socket = @server.accept

loop do
  Thread.start(socket) do |client|
    # ...
  end
end
```

accepts a single connection and then creates new threads as fast as it can, passing each thread the same `socket` object, so all of the threads start reading data from the same socket concurrently.

To avoid this, you have to move the `accept` call into the loop:

```
loop do
  socket = @server.accept

  Thread.start(socket) do |client|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Or simply:

```
loop do
  Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
    # ...
  end
end
```

`accept` immediately *blocks* to wait for a new connection, effectively pausing the loop. Once a connection is established, it creates a new thread to handle that connection and the loop starts over.

A similar example can be found in the documentation for [`TCPServer`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html).

Comment: This makes so much sense, thank you for the detailed explanation!